# Adding a link to a Wordpress menu with php

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I have a wordpress site in which I would like to add a menu link that has php in it. 
For example:

```
<a class="dynamic-menu-item" 
  href="<?php echo $firstVariable; ?>" 
  title="<?php echo $secondVariable; ?>">
  <?php echo $LinkContent1; ?> - 
  <?php echo $LinkContent2; ?>
</a>
```

How can I make this happen? I thought about trying to add a link with a arbitrary href and title, and then changing it with php once it loads the footer, but I am sure there is a better way to do this in the functions.php file. I am not that great with php yet, so this would also help me learn more. Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code in your `functions.php` file will add the navigation link to the end of your WordPress menu.

```
function my_nav_wrap() {
    $wrap  = '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">';
    $wrap .= '%3$s';
    $wrap .= '<li class="CHANGEME">';
    $wrap .= '<a class="dynamic-menu-item" href="'. echo $firstVariable .'" title="'. echo $secondVariable .'">'. echo $LinkContent1; .' - '. echo $LinkContent2 .'</a>';
    $wrap .= '</li>';
    $wrap .= '</ul>';
    return $wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a menu in your theme, first register a menu for your theme.

```
function register_my_menu()
{
    register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Menu Principal', 'your_trad' ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
```

then you can edit your menu in backend.

Just add it to your header.php

```
wp_nav_menu('primary');
```

[wp_nav_menu](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

Comment: I have a menu made for it already and the links for it are normal,  but I want the 4th one to be "dynamic". Since it's already made how can I edit the fourth one?